# 2 +2 equals what in octal when running on the moon?

Tags: android

this is just a test.

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie
I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie
I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie
I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

I struggle with arithmetic

I tried using my noggin but no workie

Answer (score 6):

I also struggle with arithmetic but should be 5.

Comment: Correct! and I have to type more

Comment: Here is another comment about this solution!